# Allow window to be resized to make expanding pixmap smaller in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QLabel` showing a `QPixmap` that has both horizontal and vertical policies set to expanding. I have written separate code to automatically scale the pixmap according to the size of the widget, but the window cannot be resized to make the image smaller than it is, and it results in it not being able to be made smaller. How do I allow the window to be resized freely?

Resizing code:

```
def resizeEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QResizeEvent):
    self.page.setPixmap(
        self.loader.img.scaled(
        self.page.width(), self.page.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio
        )
    )
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show your code -- preferably as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to inherit from `QWidget` override `paintEvent` and use `QTransform` to scale image to fit.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class ImageLabel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._image = None

    def setImage(self, image):
        self._image = image
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self._image is None or self._image.isNull():
            return
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        imageWidth = self._image.width()
        imageHeight = self._image.height()
        r1 = width / imageWidth
        r2 = height / imageHeight
        r = min(r1, r2)
        x = (width - imageWidth * r) / 2
        y = (height - imageHeight * r) / 2
        painter.setTransform(QtGui.QTransform().translate(x, y).scale(r,r))
        painter.drawImage(QtCore.QPointF(0,0), self._image)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    label = ImageLabel()
    label.setImage(QtGui.QImage("path/to/image.jpg"))
    label.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I'm loading a UI file, so I don't think I can use custom classes

Comment: You can use promoted widgets to use custom classes

Comment: @mugiseyebrows Note: with the above code, using the class as a child that is part of a layout will result in a widget that will most probably be *not* shown. It should *at least* provide a `sizeHint()` override and, possibly, implement `heightForWidth()`.

Comment: @musicamante providing `sizeHint()` is a good practice indeed, but "most probably be not shown" is not true, it could end up with zero size in some cases when stretches involved, but most likely it will be visible and have adequate size anyway.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows "most likely" is not a valid assumption. Just adding it to a simple widget with a layout will make it invisible, not to mention the quite common case of an expanding widget in the same layout. `sizeHint()` *must* be overridden for a basic QWidget subclass, or at least explicitly set a minimum size.

Comment: @musicamante no, adding to widget with layout will not make it invisible, unless you add it with zero stretch and only if there are other expanding widgets in it. It will visible coexist with expanding widget having non-zero stretching factor.

Comment: @musicamante "must be overridden" is not true, if it was, `sizeHint()` would be abstract, it has default implementation for a reason. Overriding it may actualy have drawbacks, for example if you have two widgets that have nonzero size hint, you cannot preserve constant ratio between them on resize, say you want second to always be twice as big as first - you just use stretch factor 1 and 2 and you're done, with sizehints ratio will be off.

Comment: No, it will *not*, not on *any* platform. A basic QWidget with a boxed layout and just your widget will potentially make the window extremely small (with the basic size limitation of the OS, but that's irrelevant), because the `minimumSize` of the top level widget depend on its layout (or, better, the `minimumSizeHint()`), and since that minimum size is computed on the size hint of the contents and the widget has *no* size hint, the result is a possibly 0-size widget. That "must" is obviously referred to the conceptual requirement. There's a reason for which ***all*** Qt widget implement it.

Comment: You're not required to override it because it's not a requirement for its existence, but any proper widget should always implement it. Your example is invalid, because the stretch has a control over the hint and the overall layout, and, most importantly, it's *not* required to set stretch factors. If the size hint is implemented, and no stretch is set, the widget sizes will always be proportional, based on their size policy. If what you are saying were true, it would be impossible to properly use stretch factors with any standard widget.

Comment: @musicamante if no stretch is set and sizehint implemented widgets get equal portion of space that *exceeds* sum of sizehints, so if sizehints differs widget sizes will be different and sizes ratio will not be constant.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows And so? If the size hint is different, that's because the widget *has* a different requirement. Exactly like two combo boxes can have different size hints based on their contents. If the developer doesn't like that behavior, then they *can* override that using appropriate stretch factors and minimum sizes, but the point remains: unless special behavior is required, a widget must be able to be properly visible ***no matter*** if other widgets have expanding policies and/or stretch factors are set (or not!), so, it either has a minimum size, or a *valid* size hint.

Comment: Note that this is not just about "good practice", it's clearly written in the [documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-hints-and-size-policies): "When implementing a new widget, it is almost always useful to reimplement sizeHint() to provide a reasonable default size"; and for `sizeHint()` they add that "The default implementation returns an invalid size if there is no layout". If *any* other sibling item has a valid size hint/policy that exceeds the possible space available for a non-hint widget, the former will take as much space as possible, at the loss of the latter.

Comment: @musicamante as you mentioned, documentation says "almost always useful" not "must", it is not required, as much as setting stretch factors is not required

Comment: There's quite a big difference. The "almost always" is because a widget *can* require to have a null size hint (so it makes sense that the default behavior returns that), while the stretch factor is used to *override* the hint or policy *in case* the default behavior doesn't suffice; of course you can specify a stretch or minimum size, but a good widget (especially a *display* widget) should be able to be *automatically* visible by default. For instance, a basic window with a QHBoxLayout having your above widget and a button will look [like this](//i.stack.imgur.com/346ca.png).

Comment: @musicamante what is the chance that top level widget (window) is not created in designer? *Good* top level widget *should be* created in designer so it will *never* look like you example. You can break any system by cherrypicking situation when it fails. When one say "should" or "should not" he talks opitions. Opinions are neither facts nor rules, they are recomendations.

Comment: That has nothing to do with cherrypicking. Coincidentally *you* say that a "good top level window *should* be created in Designer." First of all, there are *lots* of people that doesn't use Designer (by choice or due to some requirement). That doesn't mean their UIs are badly designed or their choice is poor, as *that* is a matter of opinion. I sincerely don't understand why you keep forcing your *opinion* (which is yours and I respect it, even if I don't agree): I simply pointed out a *clear* issue that could be easily fixed by following good practice and the suggestions of the documentation.

Comment: @musicamante and I agreed with you on main topic